# JavaScript - hide element when click outside not working on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Hiding modal windows works fine on desktop computer with this code

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    if ($("#full_window_dim").is(':visible') && !$("#hodnotenie_hl_okno").is(e.target) && $("#hodnotenie_hl_okno").has(e.target).length === 0){
        $("#full_window_dim").fadeOut();
        $('html, body').removeClass('stop-scrolling');
}
});
```

but this code is not working on mobile phones (I have tried with iPhone 5 - Safari)

How can I hide the element when users taps outside of the window on mobile phones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use touchstart for phones since most devices do not understand the mouse events.

here's the code. you can include as many events you want.

```
function HideModal(){
    if ($("#full_window_dim").is(':visible') && !$("#hodnotenie_hl_okno").is(e.target) && $("#hodnotenie_hl_okno").has(e.target).length === 0){
        $("#full_window_dim").fadeOut();
        $('html, body').removeClass('stop-scrolling');
    }
}

 $(document).on({
        "touchstart": function (event) { HideModal(); },
        "mouseup": function (event) { HideModal(); }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define "body{cursor:pointer}" for your mobile css, then Safari Mobile behaviors as a click, not tap. But I'm not sure if it's an optimal way. I just tried it and worked for me.